# Clojure - "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: seesaw.core.proxy"

Tags: java, user-interface, clojure

I'm currently learning Clojure, and I haven't worked with any Lisp dialect before.
So, trying to make a simple GUI test, I get a ClassCastException in seesaw.

### core.clj file:

```
(ns veg-gui.core)
(use 'seesaw.core)

(def f (frame :title "Hello world!") )


(defn -main [& args] 
  ( (config! f :content "Hello world.")
    (-> f pack! show!) ) )
```

### The full error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: seesaw.core.proxy$javax
.swing.JFrame$Tag$a79ba523 cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
        at veg_gui.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:8)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:411)
        at user$eval5181.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6501)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6477)
        at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2797)
        at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:297)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:316)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:349)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:427)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

(Also, I'm running this with `lein run`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn -main [& args] 
  ( (config! f :content "Hello world.")
    (-> f pack! show!) ) )
```

You have a superfluous set of parens around your function body. Compare to the following:

```
(defn -main [& args] 
  (config! f :content "Hello world.")
  (-> f pack! show!))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seesaw is not included into Clojure core, so, as in any other programming language, you need to include this library into your project. With Leiningen it's pretty easy - just add `[seesaw "x.y.z"]` (where "x.y.z" is the version) to your `project.clj`. More details and examples on project [home page](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw#tldr).

**UPD.** I payed more attention to your exception and your code. You have an error at line:

```
( (config! f :content "Hello world.")
```

Unlike most other languages, in Lisp brackets play more important role than just grouping arguments. When you write:

```
(foo ...)
```

`foo` is expected to be function (instance of `IFn`). Thus, Clojure tries to treat expression `(config! f :content "Hello world.")` as function, which is not true, so exception is thrown. To fix it just remove additional brackets:

```
(defn -main [& args] 
  (config! f :content "Hello world.")
  (-> f pack! show!))
```

Note, however, that writing expressions sequentially in Clojure is not always possible. Normally you have to use `do` to perform several actions one after another. Fortunately, `defn` includes `do` implicitly, so you don't need explicit one.

Comment: I already have included it in `project.clj`.
Anyway, thank you for your help :P

Comment: Ah, I'm being late :) I see that other folks have already pointed out to the main error.